# Python on Visual Studio Error

Tags: python

Can somebody help me identify the error here? I am using Python on Visual Studio, and I have copied the code from another source. When I paste the code into a playground like Ideone.com, the program runs without issue. Only when I paste  into visual studio do I get an error. The error is in the last two lines of code that begin with "print". This is probably a huge noob question, but I am a beginner. Help!

```
import hashlib as hasher
import datetime as date

# Define what a Snakecoin block is
class Block:
  def __init__(self, index, timestamp, data, previous_hash):
    self.index = index
    self.timestamp = timestamp
    self.data = data
    self.previous_hash = previous_hash
    self.hash = self.hash_block()

  def hash_block(self):
    sha = hasher.sha256()
    sha.update(str(self.index) + str(self.timestamp) + str(self.data) + str(self.previous_hash))
    return sha.hexdigest()

# Generate genesis block
def create_genesis_block():
  # Manually construct a block with
  # index zero and arbitrary previous hash
  return Block(0, date.datetime.now(), "Genesis Block", "0")

# Generate all later blocks in the blockchain
def next_block(last_block):
  this_index = last_block.index + 1
  this_timestamp = date.datetime.now()
  this_data = "Hey! I'm block " + str(this_index)
  this_hash = last_block.hash
  return Block(this_index, this_timestamp, this_data, this_hash)

# Create the blockchain and add the genesis block
blockchain = [create_genesis_block()]
previous_block = blockchain[0]

# How many blocks should we add to the chain
# after the genesis block
num_of_blocks_to_add = 20

# Add blocks to the chain
for i in range(0, num_of_blocks_to_add):
  block_to_add = next_block(previous_block)
  blockchain.append(block_to_add)
  previous_block = block_to_add
  # Tell everyone about it!
  print "Block #{} has been added to the blockchain!".format(block_to_add.index)
  print "Hash: {}\n".format(block_to_add.hash)
```

Comment: Would you care to also share the error with us?

Comment: the error you get??

Comment: what is the error that you have

Comment: Might be a Python 2.x vs. 3.x issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio and most other editors, they are updated to the most recent python, also meaning that you have to place parentheses after the print statement.
For example:

```
print("hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio runs Python 3.x.x, so, you have to write the print sentences on this way:

```
print('String to print')
```

Because in Python 3 print is a function, not a reserved word like in Python 2.